# Find substring in very big file(javaSE)

Tags: java, regex, substring

I need to find a substring in a very big text file (5-10GB). What do you advise me for easy and fast file processing of this size?

UPD:
This algorithm searches for a word in the file, but it seems to me that vryat it will easily handle large files:

```
File textFile = new File("text.txt");

        BufferedReader fileOut = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( textFile ) );
        String s;

        int a = 1;
        while((s = fileOut.readLine()) != null) {
            if(s.contains("findword"))
            System.out.println(a + ": " + s);
            a++;
        }

        fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Will you be finding just one sub-String and then done? Or will you be repeatedly extracting Strings from the text?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I need to find a word in a file and output a string which contains the word. For example myWordWhatIneed file.txt, and the program goes through the files and output lines that contain the word. After that offers re-enter the word file and where to look

Comment: I would suggest to use Lucene, so index the file, and do what ever you want. It would be much more faster then other thigs, and you will be able to do more advanced things then just contains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improve BufferedReader Speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922441/improve-bufferedreader-speed)

Comment: like the duplicate says, you're limited by your hard drive reading speed here. No code won't help that unless you change your approach (by somehow having the file preindexed or in memory).

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having?  The code seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take a look at Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm.